# How to delete a blob after a duration?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to delete a blob using any settings in the Azure portal or via code in c#?

Let's say, I am creating log files and uploading it to a blob container. I would like to delete all the log files which are older than a week time.

Comment: You may have a look at the following article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blob-storage-lifecycle-management-public-preview/

Comment: You also can use [Azure automation powershell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual-powershell) or webjobs to do that. Write some code and then set a schedule to delete them periodically.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the **Tasks** option under **Automation** section.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want to look into azure blob storage lifecycle management:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-blob-storage-lifecycle-management-public-preview/

Comment: but this is old documentation. I checked in the portal, I don't see the option "Life cycle management". :(

Comment: See the Tasks option under automation.

Answer (score 0):

@savagepanda is right. Azure Blob Storage has support for lifecycle management.

[Manage the Azure Blob storage lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts)

> Azure Blob storage lifecycle management offers a rich, rule-based
>   policy for GPv2 and Blob storage accounts. Use the policy to
>   transition your data to the appropriate access tiers or expire at the
>   end of the data's lifecycle.
>
> The lifecycle management policy lets you:
>
> Transition blobs to a cooler storage tier (hot to cool, hot to
>   archive, or cool to archive) to optimize for performance and cost
>   Delete blobs at the end of their lifecycles Define rules to be run
>   once per day at the storage account level Apply rules to containers or
>   a subset of blobs (using prefixes as filters)

[image: Azure Lifecycle Management Rule]

Comment: If I set this policy, is it going to be applied on all blobs? I am looking to somehow delete specifics blobs after a period of time

Comment: At the time of this comment, this option is available as Tasks under the Automation section.