# Delete files older than X number of days from Azure Blob Storage using Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to create an Azure function that deletes files from azure blob storage when last modifed older than 30 days.
Can anyone help or have a documentation to do that?

Comment: Hi Dani, welcome to SO. You've got some downvotes because people answering questions usually like to see that you have put in some work already. So did you do some research/googling yourself and at what exact point are you blocked.
You can definitely do this with Azure Functions. Have a look at [Timer Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer) and the [CloudBlobClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-samples-dotnet?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json)

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65702387/838301) for a similar scenario

Answer (score 45):

Assuming your storage account's type is either `General Purpose v2 (GPv2)` or `Blob Storage`, you actually don't have to do anything by yourself. Azure Storage can do this for you.

You'll use `Blob Lifecycle Management` and define a policy there to delete blobs if they are older than 30 days and Azure Storage will take care of deletion for you.

You can learn more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts.

Comment: I can't for the life of me find an option for "Lifecycle Management". Is it still there?

Comment: @Murphybro2 it is under 'Storage Account' -> 'Blob Service' -> 'Lifecycle Management'

Comment: I found it under 'Storage Account' -> 'Data Management' -> 'Lifecycle management'.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a Timer Trigger function, fetch the list of items from the Blob Container and delete the files which does not match your criteria of last modified date.

1. Create a [Timer Trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer#c-example).
2. Fetch the [list of blobs using CloudBlobContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#list-the-blobs-in-a-container).
3. Cast the blob items to proper type and [check LastModified property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266792/getting-the-latest-file-modified-from-azure-blob).
4. [Delete the blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497399/how-to-delete-files-from-blob-container) which doesn't match criteria.

I hope that answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

I have used HTTP as the trigger as you didn't specify one and it's easier to test but the logic would be the same for a Timer trigger etc. Also assumed C#:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [Blob("sandbox", Connection = "StorageConnectionString")] CloudBlobContainer container,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    // Get a list of all blobs in your container
    BlobResultSegment result = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);

    // Iterate each blob
    foreach (IListBlobItem item in result.Results)
    {
        // cast item to CloudBlockBlob to enable access to .Properties
        CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

        // Calculate when LastModified is compared to today
        TimeSpan? diff = DateTime.Today - blob.Properties.LastModified;
        if (diff?.Days > 30)
        {
            // Delete as necessary
            await blob.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(null);
}
```

**Edit** - How to download JSON file and deserialize to object using `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var json = await blob.DownloadTextAsync();
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Comment: this is super helpful. any idea how to deserialize each blob into a specific DTO?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' not quite sure what you mean? What is the content of your blob?

Comment: it would be a json payload that i would like to deserialize into a regular c# clas