# Delete old azure blobs

Tags: azure-blob-storage, date

I want to use the following method to delete 30 day old blobs.
However, it seems that the part of "sourceBlob.getProperties().getLastModified().getTime();" generates an exception.
What could be the possible solutions?
The exception message shows null only.
The Azure Storage type is Storage (general purpose v1)

```
public static void deleteOldBlobs(String source) {
    try {
        System.out.println("deleteOldBlobs started");
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount
                .parse(PropertyUtil.getProperty("storageConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer = blobClient.getContainerReference(source);
        long daysBack = 30;
        System.out.println(daysBack);
        long cutoff = (daysBack * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        for (ListBlobItem blobItem : sourceContainer.listBlobs()) {
            String sourceFileName = new File(blobItem.getUri().toString()).getName();
            System.out.println(sourceFileName);
            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFileName);
            System.out.println(sourceBlob.getProperties().getLastModified().getTime());
            long diff = new Date().getTime()- sourceBlob.getProperties().getLastModified().getTime();

            if (diff > cutoff) {
                sourceBlob.deleteIfExists();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("deleteOldBlobs ended");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? Please edit your question and include those details.

Comment: Also, please see this if your storage account's type is either General Purpose v2 (GPv2) or Blob Storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903837/delete-files-older-than-x-number-of-days-from-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-fun/56906611#56906611.

Comment: I only got a null for the exception message.  The storage account type is Storage (general purpose v1). I will add the above information to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call [`downloadAttributes()`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlob.html#downloadAttributes()) method to populate the properties of the blob.

Your following line of code:

```
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFileName);
```

is simply creating an instance of `CloudBlockBlob` with the properties set with default values. When you call `downloadAttributes` method, a network call will be made and blob's attributes will be fetched.

So your code would be:

```
CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob = sourceContainer.getBlockBlobReference(sourceFileName);
sourceBlob.downloadAttributes();
System.out.println(sourceBlob.getProperties().getLastModified().getTime());
```

Considering you have already listed the blobs, you can cast your `blobItem` as a `CloudBlob` and then you should not have to fetch the attributes (which makes a network call and will make the entire process much slower and error prone).

Comment: Your cast solution is so clean and efficient!