# storage account - export blob size and date

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

Today I have a storage account with 500 blob containers and 30 million blobs

I need to get or export the modification date and size of each blob.

As a first measure I don't want to change anything to cold or archive. I just want to see with an export the date of each blob and its size

Any ideas to obtain this data?

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903837/delete-files-older-than-x-number-of-days-from-azure-blob-storage-using-azure-fun/56906611#56906611. In short, you need not write any code. Simply define a Blob Lifecycle Management policy and that will take care of changing the access tier of blobs based on its age.

Comment: as a first measure I don't want to change anything to cold or archive. I just want to see with an export the date of each blob and its size